# Don't have access to file system in android cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I don't have access to the file system from my cordova app.

I've followed [**these instructions**](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#The%20Command-line%0AInterface):
 1. Added plugin: `>cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git`
 2. Added plugin: `>cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git`
 3. Added (in app/config.xml, after build this info also goes to app/res/xml/config.xml):

```
<feature name="File">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer" />
</feature>
```

1. Added (in app/AndroidManifest.xml):

> < uses-permission
>   android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

1. `>cordova prepare`
2. `>cordova build`
3. `>cordova run android`

As a result I can not open and save files from my hybrid javascript-android cordova app. The same app works well in chrome desktop browser.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You're using Cordova 3.0? There is a new File and FileTransfer plugin in Cordova 3.4, maybe you can try that.

Comment: @MBillau, I've just updated Cordova to version 3.4. How to update plugins?

Comment: @MBillau, I've reinstalled all plugins. still doesn't work.